# Json object not being passed to web api method

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, asp.net-web-api

I've been at this for hours now and still not got it right...  someone please put me out of my misery!

javascript:

```
        var calcParams = {}
        calcParams.calcName="gwp_mat";
        calcParams.components=124.332;

        //return manager.impactCalc(calcName, componentArray)
        return postData("{calcParams2:" + JSON.stringify(calcParams) + "}")
            .then(querySucceeded)
            .fail(queryFailed);


    function postData(cp) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json",
            url: "/api/breeze/testCalc",
            data: cp,
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
                return data;
            },
            error: function (error) {
                jsonValue = jQuery.parseJSON(error.responseText);
            }
        });
    }
```

model:

```
Public Class calcParams2
    Public calcName As String
    Public calcNumber As Double
End Class
```

Server code:

```
<System.Web.Services.WebMethod()> _
Public Function testCalc(cp As calcParams2) As Double
    Dim c As New calcs
    Return cp.calcNumber
End Function
```

If I debug it, the "cp" parameter in the javascript postData function is:

```
"{calcParams2:{"calcName":"gwp_mat","components":124.332}}"
```

and yet in my web method, calcname is "nothing" and components is "0.0"

If I don't use JSON.Stringify I get a null object in my web method.  I think I had one version of code where the calcName was passed but the components value was still zero. That was when I just called "return postData(JSON.stringify(calcParams))" I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to send the object parameters in the JSON:

```
return postData(JSON.stringify(calcParams)) ...
```

However your JQuery Object needs to have the same parameter names as your Server object. Change your server object to be:

```
Public Class calcParams2
    Public calcName As String
    Public components As Double
End Class
```

OR change your client object:

```
var calcParams = {}
calcParams.calcName="gwp_mat";
calcParams.calcNumber=124.332;
```

Comment: jQuery does all the encoding/stringifying for you - you can pass the object directly. In addition to making the server side edits as suggested, the OP should just be doing this: `return postData({calcParams2:calcParams})`

Comment: Doh! I created "calcparams2" as a copied test one and forgot to change the second property name.  Man, that was dumb.  However... Only Jonny S's answer works. I have to have the JSON.stringify call in there or else the web method receives nothing.  I tried with ({calcParams2: calcParams}) and nothing got through. For some reason I need "stringify" in there for it to work. I have no idea why...